# Type of screen/UI pattern?

Tags: website-design, navigation, design-patterns, interface, browse

What is the common name for this type of marketplace browsing landing page?

I'm looking for inspiration for the UI (and interactions patterns) for this type of screen - a marketplace landing page for explorative browsing (browse without a specific objective) or goal-oriented search (know what I want, want to get there using search/filtering). Most types of pages have a common name (e.g. Landing page, Galley, product page), but I can't figure out a name/keyword for these ones.

[image: Deliveroo landing page]

[image: Airbnb landing page]

[image: Groupon landing page]

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be no unified term for this, the pictures on your screenshots serve different goals. Deliveroo wants to show the broad selection of food options, Airbnb tries to tempt you with ideas based on your previous trips, and Groupon attracts your attention through discounts, etc.

However, I've met such terms as Products Showcase, used by the [Word Press Product Gallery plugin](https://demo.accesspressthemes.com/wordpress-plugins/wp-product-gallery/#)

Pttrns.com use the term [Discovery](https://pttrns.com/?scid=46). By the way, you can browse specifically the Airbnb ui patterns there: https://pttrns.com/applications/86

And finally, I've extracted a nice article from my bookmarks that discusses pretty much of what you are asking, I suppose: [Homepage Usability: Can Users Infer the Breadth of Your Product Catalog?](https://baymard.com/blog/inferring-product-catalog-from-homepage) They say that

> the overall goal is to ensure that the homepage conveys a visually
>   representative picture of the site’s offerings so that first-time
>   visitors will instinctively draw appropriate conclusions

The article does not introduce any specific term related to your question. Yet it might help you in your search of robust strategies for building a good home/landing page if this is your final goal.

Answer (score 1):

Could be described as **having a ["tiled" or "card"](https://uxdesign.cc/not-just-boxes-card-components-in-design-systems-568e97501ba0) interface** (Microsoft calls them "tiles", Google calls them "cards", but that article discusses several different implementations of them).

The bulk of the page is made up of images that allow the user to browse easily by simply scrolling until something catches their eye. Selecting one of the images typically either takes them into exploring that category, or provides them a detail page of the product, service, etc.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, however, looking for "Card interface" mostly provided me with examples of galleries. archives, or search results. What I'm looking for is how a card-based layout like this is called when it's used for marketplaces landing pages (for example, the moment you land on Amazon). I'm probably looking for a UI slang rather than UX specification - correct me if I'm wrong.